# How to add glyphs from one font into another?

Tags: windows, software-rec, fonts, unicode

I want to create a new font (TTF or OTF) that contains certain glyphs from one font (e.g. Arial) and certain glyps from another font (i.e. Courier). I know the unicode IDs for the glyphs.

About 200 glyphs (greek, cyrillic, etc) need to be copied over.

Any tools that could do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/)**

> An outline font editor that lets you create your own postscript,
>   truetype, opentype, cid-keyed, multi-master, cff, svg and bitmap (bdf,
>   FON, NFNT) fonts, or edit existing ones. Also lets you convert one
>   format to another. FontForge has support for many macintosh font
>   formats.

[image]

Comment: thanks i will look into this. but does it support copying many glyphs at once? i dont want to copy paste every single glyph, cause  i have about 200 of them.

Comment: There is Merge font command